# Downloading ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I just downloaded ASP.NET along with some other things(SP1 and such) Total: 9XX MB.
I had to restart my computer and now when I try to open a new project via my VS2010, I see nothing different, I can't find the Web Form option, Here's the URL I downloaded from:
http://www.asp.net/downloads
Thanks!

Comment: uh...this should be closed soon.

Comment: @Timmerz Why.. I really don't know what to do, could you please help me instead of saying it?

Comment: @idish Because, this question does not belong here. If you have a problem with ASP.NET, go to ASP.NET forums, and ask there.

Comment: try following some beginners tutorials by doing some searches in google or something, as david suggested.

Comment: HEY! Now my answer looks dumb!  Unfair edit!  FOUL!  Where's the ref?  Red flag, red flag...   (Sorry, just blowing off steam near the end of the day.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now you need to go to http://www.asp.net/get-started and start learning.  (Of course, there are other places you can go to learn, but this is an obvious choice).

Comment: I don't know why I posted that as an answer instead of a comment.  I'm going to lose any points when the question gets closed and then deleted anyway.  :P

Comment: If you help idish even a bit along the way then it's not a waste :-)